# JavaFX bidirectional binding of Array<String> to multiple TextFields

Tags: javafx, binding, textfield, listproperty

I need your help. In my entity model class I have currently

```
protected ObservableList<Double> marketSize = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
ListProperty<Double> marketSizeProperty = new SimpleListProperty<Priority>(marketSize);
```

In the UI I have a fixed number of 5 TextFields like so
[image]

In the fxml file

```
<TextField fx:id="sizeLYTextField" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
<TextField fx:id="sizeLY1TextField" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
<TextField fx:id="sizeLY2TextField" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
```

and so on.

Is there a way to bind each of the TextFields in the UI to a different element of the array?  Like

```
sizeLYTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(model.marketSizeProperty.get(0));
```

what is obviously not working.

I thought about an array of StringProperties, but since I have a number of rows beneath each other, each having 5 TextFields I would have quite a number of single StringProperty boiler plate code. Maybe TextFields are not the ideal UI element?! Let me know what you think.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: To clarify, you want to bidirectionally bind a `Property<String>` with the value at a specific index in an `ObservableList<Double>`, correct?

Comment: [mcve] please .. snippets are not good enough (not only because they typically don't compile, as your first doesn't) That said: I would look at the modeling first, positions in lists/arrays are rarely semantically strong enough (though they might :) Also, this looks like a tabular structure, did you consider using a tableView?

Comment: Are you sure you need seperate properties? also the boilerplate code can easily be reduced to a minimum (perhaps even further depending on the scene structure): `private static StringProperty[] toPropertyArray(TextField... fields) { return Stream.of(fields).map(TextField::textProperty).toArray(StringProperty[]::new); }` (Mapping function could easily be replaced with code creating & binding a property.)

Comment: @kleopatra: In theory I agree that a TableView would be easier, but the layout is what it is. I have to deal with the optics and as far I can say I can not alter the UI of of a TableView to the shown layout.

Comment: @Fabian: This is great code, far beyond my abilities. Does the map command does the same like bindbidirectional?

Comment: `Stream<X>.map` gets a `Function<X, Y>` converting X and returns a `Stream<Y>`. In this case it simply converts a `TextField` to the text property it contains. There is no binding necessary, since you're working with the original property directly, if you use my code...